# Should my viewmodel value type properties be nullable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I've been making my viewmodel properties nullable for quite some time now.  My reasoning is that when a validation occurs, I don't want default values inserted into the fields that the user left empty, but are required.

I mark my required fields with required, for course, but this got me to thinking that i'm losing a great deal of fidelity in the object model by doing this.

Of course my domain classes are only nullable when they can actually be null.

Should my viewmodel properties be nullable when the domain model requires them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should my viewmodel properties be nullable when the domain model requires them?

Yes, they should in order to properly perform validation on the view model. When you ensure that the view model is valid and map this view model back to the actual domain model in your mapping layer you will be certain that a value would be provided for this property.

Comment: That's why i've been doing it.  But it does seem like we're losing a great deal by making something both nullable and required.

Comment: @Mystere Man, that's what view models are supposed to do. They are supposed to reflect a view. On the view you have a text field. This text field could be left empty by the user. So your view model should be nullable. On the other hand your business rules dictate that a value should be provided for this field. Thus you decorate it with the Required attribute to ensure that your domain model is in a valid state when you map it from your view model.

Comment: I understand the case for text fields, but i was referring to value types, like ints, DateTimes, etc..  if you don't make them nullable, then on validation it comes back with default values for those.

Comment: @Mystere Man, in HTML there is no such notion as ints, DateTimes, etc... In HTML you have input fields of type text (and other types of course). Those input fields represent string values and could be left empty by the user. So you should design your view models in such a way to reflect this.

Comment: A semi-common/related pattern is to have ALL ViewModel properties as strings (or lists of strings).

Comment: @ckittel, sure, that's a possibility, but could make the mapping between the view models and the domain models a little harder.

Comment: Indeed, it does have drawbacks.  But some people see the view-side benefits outweigh the server-side mapping.

Comment: I'm aware of what you're saying, but since MVC does model binding and automatic conversion... I see no reason to use text types in the viewmodel

Comment: @Mystere Man, what do you mean by *using text types in the view model*? If you don't use nullable types it would be difficult for you to distinguish between the default value of the value type (for example 0 for integers) and empty string which could be entered by the user. That's the reason why I would recommend you using nullable integer in this case. As far as your domain model is concerned, well, that's another story => it would reflect your business requirements.

Comment: Sorry, i meant meant using a string type rather than the actual type.  I think we're in agreement, but it's nice to get validation (no pun intended) that i've been doing it the right way.

Comment: String types on your viewmodel can be useful when dealing with globalization issues, like dots and comma's, and datetime notations.

Comment: @Robin van der Knaap, personally I prefer custom model binders for this case.

Comment: @Darin, thanx for the tip, haven't thought of that. That would enable me to remove some cruft from my viewmodels.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, after 10 years is your opinion still the same as the answer you provided? Thank you.