# Hidden int property validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to validate hidden integer property can you please suggest better way

```
public class Model
{
        [Display(Name="Theme"),Required(ErrorMessage="Please choose your theme")]
        public int ThemeId { get; set; }
}
```

In view

```
@Html.Hidden(m=>m.ThemeId)
```

And this output `<input type="hidden" bbla bla value="0"/>`

Problem is currently this field is valid because 0 is default value of int property so every required in property is default valid. So I have to make it invalid.

My Solution is

Simply using `Range(1,int.MaxValue)` attribute for that property.

I am just asking to know that is it best solution to this problem or not . If not can you please point better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this same problem and haven't come up with a better solution.

It's perfectly valid as you are saying that the range of **values** for this property is `1..MaxInt`.

The only other solution I can see is to make it a nullable integer and then testing that the value is not null. However, that would include the value zero and negative values so you still have to check that it's a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives:

- Use `Nullable` properties (`int?` in this case)
- Use `string` to allow empty fields

For this scenario, the preferred way is to make the property in the ViewModel nullable, and mark it as required.

The question [Should my viewmodel value type properties be nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210548/should-my-viewmodel-value-type-properties-be-nullable) also contains some information and opinions on both approaches.